# pymysql : EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:

Tags: python, installation, package, putty, pymysql

I am facing a problem while installing pymysql package in jupyter @ Server. Steps followed by me are as belows. Request to help call on 8802329198)

Note: ( I am doing this on server jupyter which i logged in using putty http://localhost:8888/tree/)

1:
pip install pymysql

ollecting pymysql
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2c/57/af502e0e113f139b3f3add4f1efba899a730a365d2264d476e85b9591da5/PyMySQL-0.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pymysql
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

WARNING: You are using pip version 19.1.1, however version 20.2.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.

Also tried below code for resolve same:

2:
python3 -m pip install PyMySQL

File "", line 1
python3 -m pip install PyMySQL
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

After done above activities , still i am unable to import pymysql:
import pymysql

---

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 import pymysql

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysql'

Answer (score 0):

Please try installing `pymysql` package in your home directory like this:

```
pip install --user pymysql
```

In general, `pip` defaults to installing Python packages to a system directory (for instance `/usr/local/lib/python3.7`) and that requires root access. But `--user` makes pip install packages in your home directory instead, which doesn't require any special privileges.

Another option would be using `sudo`:

```
sudo pip install pymysql
```

Comment: Thank you so much. it was helpful.  Installed successfully ..